# setdiff function

Tags: r

[image]

```
[1] 1 2 4 5 6
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
[1] 6
```

As shown in the image, a is {1 , 2, 4, 5, 6} and b is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. I used setdiff to find the difference between this two dataframes. However, the result shows 6 which is not my goal. I want it to show 3 & 6.

So what the syntax/function should I use to get the correct result?

cheers

I tried to use setdiff.

and I expect to show 3 & 6 in my syntax.

Comment: You want `dplyr::symdiff(c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`, or other answers provided in the link

Comment: Hello Maël, I just tried this syntax dplyr::symdiff(c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).
There is an error saying Error: 'symdiff' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'. 

I also tried symdiff(a,b) , Error in symdiff(a, b) : could not find function "symdiff"

Comment: `symdiff` is recent. Try to update `dplyr` first

Comment: That works for me now. Thank you so much, Maël.